# PowerBI automate visuals

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way how to create visuals dynamically?
Simply speaking, once data is refreshed it shows 7 customers. PowerBI will show me 7 graphs for each one. Next time I refresh I have 12, so I will have 12 visuals.

Comment: How about custom visual Small Multiple Line Chart?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Jacek Wróbel; I did not know about this visual.
Reviewing this I noticed Small multiples were added into PowerBI December 2020 and while I was hoping for the Donut visuals, it's more then enough for the solution I was looking for.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-small-multiples-public-preview/